# Password Protect PHP File

Tags: php

In PHP, how can I password protect my php file so I have to go to:

http://www.example.com/upload.php/?pass=password

If you know how to do this I would greatly appreciate a snippet of code.

Comment: Having a password in the URL is a very bad idea. Gets stored in the browsers history

Comment: why would you even pass it to the browser?

Comment: please be clear, a password to protect (your php file?), against what thing?

Answer (score 0):

I will stear you to $_GET which reads the url Path, but please note that this is nothing but insecure.

Comment: This is what I am using currently but its giving me an error:
`<?php
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
if(!isset($pass)) {
 header('Location: /notfound.html');
 exit(0);
} else {
 if($pass != 'examplepass') {
  header('Location: /notfound.html');
  exit(0);
 }
}
?>`

Comment: Which error specificly?
You should not do isset($pass) this only checks if the variable is set, not their content, do isset($_GET['pass']) to first check if it is their, then do a second if to check if the contained string matches

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I used this code. It's just for something small.

```
<?php
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
if(!isset($pass)) {
    exit(0);
} else {
    if($pass != 'examplepass') {
        exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.